# Route [marks-time] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolerp\resources\views\backEnd\partials\sidebar.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am defining the route in `sidebar.blade.php` but it still show the route[marks-time] is not define and I define route in `admin.php` also here is the code:

```php
Route::get('marks-time', ['as' => 'marks-time', 'uses' => 'SmExaminationController@markstime'])->name('marks-time')->middleware('userRolePermission:2050');
Route::post('marks-time-save', ['as' => 'marks-time-save', 'uses' => 'SmExaminationController@markstimesave'])->middleware('userRolePermission:2050');
```

Here the code (`sidebar.blade.php`):

```php
@if(userPermission(2050) && menuStatus(2050))
<li>
  <a href="{{route('marks-time')}}">@lang('lang.marks_time')</a>
</li>
@endif
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images; you got it half-right with this question, but there's no need to post an image of your `sidebar.blade.php` file; code is text, please copy, paste and format it properly in your question.

Comment: Also, please run `php artisan route:list` and check the  `Name` column for `marks-time`. It might be `admin.marks-time` if you defined it in a different file than `routes/web.php`.

Comment: okay first of all I am sorry. I will remember it at next time to not post code as image.

Comment: when i run php artisan route:list it through error this  'Unable to read key from file file://C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolerp\storage\oauth-private.key'

Comment: All good! Just try to get the formatting done correctly (I've adjusted this, if you click the edit button, you can see how I did it, try to replicate that). As for that error, I'm not familiar with that; I don't develop on Windows... `php artisan ...` commands should work just fine, but again, not sure since this is Windows. See if you can solve that issue first, then try that `artisan` command again.

Comment: Ok i am trying to solve it and thankyou for your help